# Can minimal addition chains always be built from smaller minimal ones?

Tags: arithmetic, discrete-optimization

Is there always a minimal addition chain for *n* that is the union of two minimal addition chains for some *i*, *j*, s.t. *i*+*j*=*n*, together with *n* itself? If so, can you provide a proof? And if not, what's the least counterexample?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain for the definition of addition chains.

Comment: The *union* of two chains contains for $i,j$ no number greater than $\max\{i,j\}$?!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that, of course one must also insert <i>n</i> into the addition chain for <i>n</i>. Question edited.

Comment: Of course the "union" need not be a disjoint union.

Comment: Correct. The union is never disjoint, because all addition chains start with 2.